# The bullet in itemize gone when using classicthesis with Neo Euler font, and microtype warns "Unknown slot number of character"

Tags: lists, itemize, classicthesis, euler, arsclassica

I'm using classicthesis v4.6 with XeLaTeX. By default the `eulermath` option is useless as noted in a comment in `classicthesis.sty`:

> because there is no OpenType Euler font ...

Thus I manually added `\setmathfont[math-style=upright]{Neo Euler}` in my preamble, with the font downloaded [here](https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf) (though it is marked "abandoned", I still used it since there seems to be no better solution). And suddenly there are multiple `Unknown slot number of character` errors. Though I can make these warnings disappear by

```tex
\def\MT@warn@unknown{}
```

There is an issue: the bullet of itemize is gone. How can I fix this?

Here's a MWE.

```tex
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage[eulerchapternumbers,eulermath,style=arsclassica]{classicthesis}

\setmathfont[math-style=upright]{Neo Euler}

% \makeatletter
% \def\MT@warn@unknown{}
% \makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Hello % The bullet is gone!
    \item World
\end{itemize}

$a+b=c$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you add the following instructions to the preamble, *after* the `\setmathfont` instruction:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=\textcolor{halfgray}{\textbullet}}
```

The `classicthesis` package loads the `xcolor` package (which, in turn, defines `\textcolor`) and defines the color `halfgray`.

If, for some reason, you can't load the `enumitem` package, I suggest you add the following instruction to the preamble:

```
\renewcommand\labelitemi{\textcolor{halfgray}{\textbullet}}
```

With either of these additions, your MWE produces the following output for the `itemize` list:

[image]

To my eyes, this is indistinguishable from what's produced if the `\setmathfont` instruction is omitted entirely.

Comment: Incidentally, I was not able to compile your MWE under XeLaTeX, as my TeX installation (MacTeX2020) complained about not being able to find the font "TeX Gyre Pagella". Switching to LuaLaTeX solved that problem immediately, though.

Comment: Totally unrelated, @Mico, but do you know why this is happening - why \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella} is not working and \setmainfont{texgyrepagella} is. My TeX is texlive-base-20200327-16 on Fedora 33 (the newest). Whom should this be reported to, core developers or packagers?

Comment: @PhilipPirrip - I must confess to not understanding the differences between the ways that XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX search for font files. If I remember things correctly, XeLaTeX relies exclusively on information provided by the operating system. For some reason utterly unknown to me, this information is frequently more restrictive and less flexible than what LuaLaTeX does to find font files. AFAICT, XeLaTEX's setup is not a bug but, rather, a conscious design decision. To be sure, I do not claim to understand on which basis some of these design decisions were taken.

Answer (score 1):

The annoying warnings can be removed by creating a file named `mt-NeoEuler.cfg` in the working directory containing

```
\ProvidesFile{mt-NeoEuler.cfg}
\DeclareCharacterInheritance{encoding=TU,family=NeoEuler}{}
```

The issue about the bullet is due to a wrong definition in `classicthesis-arsclassica.sty`, which has

```
\renewcommand\labelitemi{\color{CTsemi}$\bullet$}
```

instead of the correct

```
\renewcommand\labelitemi{\textcolor{CTsemi}{\textbullet}}
```

Use the fixed redefinition.

```
\begin{filecontents}{mt-NeoEuler.cfg}
\ProvidesFile{mt-NeoEuler.cfg}
\DeclareCharacterInheritance{encoding=TU,family=NeoEuler}{}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,eulermath,style=arsclassica]{classicthesis}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setsansfont{Iwona}
\setmathfont[math-style=upright]{Neo Euler}

\renewcommand\labelitemi{\textcolor{CTsemi}{\textbullet}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Hello
    \item World
\end{itemize}

$a+b=c$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that the `classicthesis` package defines both `\definecolor{CTsemi}{gray}{0.55}` and `\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}`. Hence, `halfgray` and `CTsemi` are the same -- at least according to this package.

Comment: @Mico On the other hand, `classicthesis-arsclassica.sty` uses `CTsemi`, so I'd prefer this one. There's no guarantee that `halfgray` remains the same.